# Web Deployment Projects tool and Web application project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, assemblies

Q1 - As far as I know, Visual Studio doesn’t use aspnet_compiler.exe when compiling web application projects. And since Web Deployment Projects (WDP) tool is only used for manipulation the output created by aspnet_compiler.exe, I don’t understand how VS 2008 also has an option for using WDP with web application projects?!

Q2 - What is a stock project?

thanx

**EDIT:**

So I was right about the fact that Visual Studio doesn’t use aspnet_compiler.exe when compiling web application projects?

much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Web Application Projects are real projects - they really build, and produce a single assembly in the output (bin) folder, as well as any copies of referenced assemblies, etc. This is what a Web Deployment Project will package.

It's useful to keep in mind that Web Application Projects and Web Deployment Projects were the only way to create web projects until .NET 2.0 and Visual Studio 2005. In many cases, the better question will be "how do web site pseudo-projects ever work".

Comment: Why do you consider Web Application Projects as real projects but you refer to web sites as pseudo projects?

Comment: There are too many reasons to list (as I run for the train back home), but ask yourself how many types of project in Visual Studio do not have a project file?

Comment: But why would only having a project file qualify it as a project? There must be something deeper behind it?!

Comment: There is. Lack of project file was only a hint. If everyone else has one, what's it say for web sites? If nothing else, being different means it behaves differently than anyone expects - except for "web site" developers. Why split the expertise?

Comment: To back up John's POV, in my VS2008, if I click File->Add
I have the choice of New Project or New Website, which implies even VS sees Website somewhat outside of a normal Project

Answer (score 1):

aspnet_compiler will compile .aspx/.ascx /.ashx etc.. files also (not just the code behinds). Visual studio does not. So if you want to precompile those files, use the Web Deployment projects and/or precompile manually.

Comment: I am having preservation about `ashx` files. I notices that running aspnet_compiler using switches: `Parameters: -v / -p <input path> -u -f <output path> -fixednames -errorstack` didn't compile `ashx` files